# Points on plot not printing properly on paper

Tags: r, plot, printing

So for my homework, I made several plots in R, saved them as pdfs, and put them in a LaTeX document. Here is an example of one of them:

[image]

The issue I am having is with the points; in the image, they are red points with a black outline. However, when I print the document, and I mean *physically print the document*, this is the output:

[image]

The points are just the letter "q" being printed out!

This may be the wrong place for this question, but does anyone have any idea why this is happening? This is happening for all of the plots I made with points on them.

Here is the code used to make the plot:

```
# colors that I like using
cb_pal = c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", "#CC79A7", "#F0E442", "#0072B2", 
               "#D55E00", "#999999", "#000000")

# data set
bass = data.frame(length = c(14.5, 12.5, 17.25, 14.5, 12.625, 17.75, 14.125, 12.625),
                  girth = c(9.75, 8.375, 11, 9.75, 8.5, 12.5, 9, 8.5),
                  weight = c(27, 17, 41, 26, 17, 49, 23, 16))

# manually doing least squares
X = bass$length; Y = bass$girth; W = bass$weight
X2 = X^2; X4 = X^4; Y2 = Y^2
b = sum(W*X2*Y)/sum(X4*Y2)

# making function
dev = function(x, y) {
  ans = b*(x^2)*y
  return(ans)
}

# making points
x = seq(12, 18, 0.25)
y = seq(8, 13, 0.25)
dev_plot = outer(X = x, Y = y, FUN = dev)

# plotting function
#pdf(file = "q04_plot.pdf")

par(family = "serif")

# plot of function
myp = persp(x, y, dev_plot, box = TRUE, expand = 0.4, theta = 35, phi = 15, 
            ticktype = "detailed", col = cb_pal[5], border = "black",
            xlab = "Length", ylab = "Girth", zlab = "Weight")

# plotting points
myp_pts = trans3d(x = bass$length, y = bass$girth, z = bass$weight, pmat = myp)
points(myp_pts, col = "black", bg = "red3", pch = 21, cex = 1.25)

#dev.off()
```

**EDIT** I added the color palette I used to the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is caused by a bug/mis-configuration in the poppler library used by your PDF viewer. By default, R uses the *Dingbats* font for representing the plotting symbols and the typical circle happens to be the letter 'q' in other fonts.

There's three ways to deal with it:

1. Use a different PDF viewer (e.g. Adobe Reader which is not based on poppler)
2. Update your system – it's been many years since I last encountered this. Current LINUX distributions should not have that problem.
3. Tell R to use a proper circle instead of encoding it in a symbol font:

```
pdf("myplot.pdf", useDingbats=FALSE)
plot(1:10, 1:10)
dev.off()
```

Comment: I will try this out, but I should note that when I view it using Adobe Acrobat, the points come up as circles as I want. It is *only* when I physically print the document that the points become letters.

Comment: Maybe there is somthing in the printing setup that uses poppler? E.g. a CUPS filter or similar? In any case the third option should fix that, no matter where exactly the culprit is located.

Comment: well, whatever the reason, your answer worked. I will look into it myself and update the question with more information if I find anything useful. Many thanks!